Suppose that exists a $M>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(p)| \leq M|g(x)-g(p)|$ for all $x$. Prove that if $g$ is continuous at $p$, then $f$ is as well.
"Let $f$ and $g$ be defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that exists a $M>0 \hspace{0.2cm}(\exists)$ st. $|f(x)-f(p)| \leq M|g(x)-g(p)|$ for all $x$. Prove that if $g$ is continuous at $p$, then $f$ is as well."
I want to know if my answer to this question is right:
'$g$ is continuous at $p$, so
$$\underbrace{\forall \varepsilon_2>0 \hspace{0.2cm} \exists \delta_2>0}_{*} :|x-p|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(p)|<\varepsilon_2.$$
We want to get
$$\forall \varepsilon_1>0 \hspace{0.2cm} \exists \delta_1>0 :|x-p|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon_1.$$
My ideia was to take $\delta_1=\delta_2$ and, using the fact at (*), choose $\varepsilon_2=\frac{\varepsilon_1}{M}$. The consequence is
$$|x-p|<\underbrace{\delta_2}_{\delta_1} \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(p)|<\underbrace{\frac{\varepsilon_1}{M}}_{\varepsilon_2} \Leftrightarrow M|g(x)-g(p)|<\varepsilon_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon_1.'$$

Looks good to me. Another approach is to suppose $x_k \to x$, then $g(x_k) \to g(x)$ and hence $f(x_k) \to f(x)$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You could just use the squeeze theorem.  Note moreover  that wlog $M=1$ and $f(p)=g(p)=0$.

You are on the right track!
Since $g$ is continuous at $p\in\mathbb{R}$, we may claim that
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(|x - p| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |g(x) - g(p)| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta_{\varepsilon}>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})\left(|x - p| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(p)| \leq M|g(x) - g(p)| < M\times\frac{\varepsilon}{M} = \varepsilon\right)
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $f$ is continuous.
Hopefully this helps!
